# Need help for comparing checksums of files on remote servers

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, hashsum

Algorithm:

1. Take md5sums of files/directories from all servers [Pick server-list and DIR-list from a file]
2. Compare md5sums of files from all servers with active-node [Active node can be any 1 node from server list]
3. Report incorrect/unmatched md5sum of file
4. Report last updated time of all files with incorrect md5sum and for how long they have been out-of-sync [Logic: Compare last modification time of that file with same file on Active Node]
5. Report if files are not present on any of the servers

Expected Log format:

```
[Warn]     Node Name: 192.168.1.23 | Out-ofSync-Filename: /home/user2/nginx/Templates/file34 | Last-Modified-Time: 2021-07-19 19:25:37 | Out-Of-sync-Since: 15 minutes
[CRITICAL] Node Name: 192.168.1.23 | Out-ofSync-Filename: /home/user2/nginx/Templates/file34 | Last-Modified-Time: 2021-07-19 19:25:37 | Out-Of-sync-Since: 20 minutes
```

My Script Progress :

---

```
 ### Defining Server INI files ###
    
    serverList="/home/user1/testdir/server-list"
    filesList="/home/user1/testdir/directory-list"
    
    ### Defining output files for extracting md5sums ###
    
    md5sumofDIR="/home/user1/testdir/directory-md5sum"
    filemd5sum="/home/user1/testdir/file-md5sum"
    
    ### Read Server IP from File ###
    
    for i in $(cat $serverList | awk '{print $3}'); do
     echo $i
    
    done
    
    ### Read File-List from File ###
    
    
    for j in $(cat $filesList | awk '{print $3}'); do
    
     if [[ -d $j ]]; then
        echo "$j is a directory"
         for i in $(cat $serverList | awk '{print $3}'); do
           ssh root@$i "find "$j" -type f -exec md5sum {} \;" >> "$i"
    
         done
    
    
     elif [[ -f $j ]]; then
        echo "$j is a file"
         for i in $(cat $serverList | awk '{print $3}'); do
           ssh root@$i "md5sum $j" >> "$i"
         done
     fi
    
    
    done
    
    ## Finding Active Node with a condition ##
    
    for i in $(cat $serverList | awk '{print $3}'); do
            s1=`ssh root@$i /etc/sysconfig/ha/getactive.sh`
                    if [[ $s1 == "NodeType: Active" ]]; then
                            t1=$i
                    fi
    done
    
    
    
    ## Compare md5sum of Active Node with All Nodes ##
    
    for j in $(cat $serverList | awk '{print $3}'); do
    
            f1=`grep -xvFf $t1  $j | awk '{print $2}'`
    
                    if [[ $f1 == *"/"* ]]; then
                            filestat=$(echo "Node Name: " $j "Out-ofSync-Filename: " $f1)
                            echo $filestat >> final-md5sum
                    fi
    done
    
    #### Calculating Last modifiction time of Inconsistent file ####
    var=`cat final-md5sum`
    
    if [ -n "$var" ]; then
            awk '{print $3, $5}' final-md5sum |
                    while read -r ip path; do
                            (ssh root@"$ip" "stat -c%y $path | cut -d'.' -f1" < /dev/null) >> file-stat
                    done
    fi
```

I'm stuck at further part where I'm not able to get desired log and file modification details in my log. Feel free to comment if my method is lengthy or I should follow any other approach

Comment: this feels like an awkward way to avoid running `rsync` in dry mode?

Comment: Never used rsync before. But I dont want to actually sync files betwen servers, I just want to match their md5sum and report server1:file1 is different from server2:file1 | What could be the rsync command for my scenario

Comment: `rsync --dry-run`.

Comment: why?   what does just knowing that a server is out of sync give you that's actually useful? i.e. if you know one of the servers (the "active" server) has the correct, up-to-date version of the file, then  just copy that to all of the other servers.   Better yet, if you have a bunch of mostly-identical servers that need to be kept in sync, use something like [puppet](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet) or [ansible](https://www.ansible.com) to manage them - that's what they're for.