# Compare a given number with a number from first column of required files in a folder in Bash

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm trying to compare a number with a digit from first column of required files in a folder. My current script only works if there is single line in that file.
It fails whenever any file has more than one line.

```
cat 192.168.1.2_time-final2_timepls
86.6333 /home/fes/nginx/Templates/test.default

cat 192.168.1.3_time-final2_timepls
8 /home/fes/nginx/createfile
122 /home/fes/nginx/Templates/rtPortal.default

cat 192.168.1.4_time-final2_timepls
981 /home/fes/nginx/Templates/test.default
```

My Code:

```
dir1="/home/user1/test/time-final/*_time-final2_timepls"

y=100

for files3 in $dir1; do

        z=$(cat $files3 | awk '{print $1}')

        if awk 'BEGIN{exit ARGV[1]>ARGV[2]}' "$z" "$y"
                then
                  echo "z is smaller than y"
        else
                  echo "z greater than y" "Filepath: "  $files3
        fi


done
```

Actual Output:

```
[root@user1]# ./my-script.sh
z smaller than y
z greater than y Filepath:  /home/user1/test/time-final/192.168.1.3_time-final2_timepls
z greater than y Filepath:  /home/user1/test/time-final/192.168.1.4_time-final2_timepls
```

I'm trying to get this output which will also print the line from the file if it satisfies condition z>y:

```
z smaller than y 
z smaller than y 
z greater than y Filepath:  /home/user1/test/time-final/192.168.1.3_time-final2_timepls    Filename: /home/fes/nginx/Templates/rtPortal.default 
z greater than y Filepath:  /home/user1/test/time-final/192.168.1.4_time-final2_timepls    Filename: /home/fes/nginx/Templates/test.default
```

Comment: Could you please describe what it is all your questions are about.  It feels like we're helping you build some huge sprawling piece of advanced management application, similar to Ansible,  I'm not sure what the use cases are and what the end goal might possibly be. We [asked you](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/659439/116858) whether `rsync --dry-run` would do some of what you're trying to do, or whether Ansible or some other existing management software would help, but I don't think you ever answered and it's evident that you didn't care.

Comment: ok. Here's my algorithm for what I'm building: Sample algorithm: 
1) Take md5sums of required files from all 5 servers.
2) Compare md5ums of files from all 5 servers with files on Active server 
3) Report if any file is not synced. 
4) Take care of any missing files on servers. 
5) Log the Last modification time of that file(which was not synced) and for how much time that file was not in sync.

Comment: rsync --dry-run was an option but what I need more  is "reporting" more than actually syncing files. I already have filesync deployed in my environment but if any of the file dosent get synced. I need to report/LOG that file's last modification file and for how long that file was not insync

Comment: There's something I'm missing.  If the files on the servers should be in sync with your "Active server", then why are the files _not_ in sync? Can't whoever changes them change be told to not do that? Also, why aren't the files shared via NFS or some other network file system, if the same files have to be in sync on several servers on a local network? Code like [the code I gave you](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/659676/116858) solves tiny problems, but solutions to tiny problems can't always be naively concatenated to solve larger issues.

Comment: Your previous answer really helped me a lot.  I'm given this project with respective to Reporting perspective and I cannot change existing infra so I'm kinda forced to implement this. Thanks for your concern!

Comment: You are in a maze of twisty little [XY Problems](http://xyproblem.info/), all alike.

Answer (score 0):

Anyways, I got the answer from a previous solution:

```
y=100

awk '{print $1, $2}' *_time-final2_timepls |
        while read -r num1 path1; do
        z=$num1
        if awk 'BEGIN{exit ARGV[1]>ARGV[2]}' "$z" "$y"
                then
                  echo "z is smaller than y"
        else
                  echo "z greater than y" "Filepath: "  $path1
        fi    
done
```

Output:

```
z is smaller than y
z is smaller than y
z greater than y Filepath:  /home/fes/nginx/Templates/rtPortal.default
z greater than y Filepath:  /home/fes/nginx/Templates/test.default
```